# Equidistant Grid on Map Projection

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap, map-projections

I was hoping to create an equidistant grid over Manhattan map (say 200m by 200m) projection using latitudes and longitudes not degrees. I was using basemap but couldn't figure out a way to proceed with the task. This the projection code.

```
m = Basemap(projection='mill',
        llcrnrlat= 40.6968,
        llcrnrlon= -74.0224,
        urcrnrlat= 40.8964, 
        urcrnrlon= -73.8927,
        resolution='h')
```

What will be the best way to do the above, I also need to store lat,long values of each grid vertex points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [basemap documentation](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/mapcoords.html):

> In order to plot data on a map, the coordinates of the data must be
>   given in map projection coordinates. Calling a Basemap class instance
>   with the arguments lon, lat will convert lon/lat (in degrees) to x/y
>   map projection coordinates (in meters). The inverse transformation is
>   done if the optional keyword inverse is set to True.

There is also an example in the documentation page. To adept this example to your use case, I converted the lower left corners into meters, produced a regular grid with 2000 m spacing (200 m was a bit too dense) and converted the grid back into lon/lat coordinates, which can then be used by `drawparallels()` and `drawmeridians`.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

lon0 = -74.0224
lat0 = 40.6968

m = Basemap(
    projection='mill',
    llcrnrlat= 40.6968,
    llcrnrlon= -74.0224,
    urcrnrlat= 40.8964, 
    urcrnrlon= -73.8927,
    resolution='h',
    ax = ax,
    )

x0, y0 = m(lon0, lat0)

x = np.arange(20)*2000+x0
y = np.arange(20)*2000+y0

lons, lats = m(x,y,inverse=True)    

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawstates()
m.drawmeridians(lons)
m.drawparallels(lats)

plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result of the above code]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. You are a life saver.